# Networking- Wireless and Wired not working

Tags: wireless, networking

So everything in Ubuntu has been working great until networking stopped working.  I've spent the better part of two days scouring for a fix with no luck.  Here is my info...your help would so be appreciated.

```
 grep -i eth /var/log/syslog | tail 

Sep 25 16:31:59 jj-laptop NetworkManager[970]: <info> (eth0): cleaning up... 
Sep 25 16:31:59 jj-laptop NetworkManager[970]: <info> (eth0): taking down device. 
Sep 25 16:31:59 jj-laptop kernel: [23403.998837] sky2 0000:02:00.0: eth0: disabling interface 
Sep 25 16:35:54 jj-laptop NetworkManager[970]: <info> (eth0): now managed 
Sep 25 16:35:54 jj-laptop NetworkManager[970]: <info> (eth0): device state change:    unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2] 
Sep 25 16:35:54 jj-laptop NetworkManager[970]: <info> (eth0): bringing up device. 
Sep 25 16:35:54 jj-laptop kernel: [23413.629424] sky2 0000:02:00.0: eth0: enabling interface 
Sep 25 16:35:54 jj-laptop kernel: [23413.635703] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready 
Sep 25 16:35:54 jj-laptop NetworkManager[970]: <info> (eth0): preparing device. 
Sep 25 16:35:54 jj-laptop NetworkManager[970]: <info> (eth0): deactivating device (reason 'managed') [2]
```

and then

```
ifconfig -a

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:17:42:14:e9:e1  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1 
          RX packets:4605 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:287 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:315161 (315.1 KB)  TX bytes:63680 (63.6 KB) 
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0 
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host 
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1 
          RX packets:13018 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:13018 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:880484 (880.4 KB)  TX bytes:880484 (880.4 KB) 

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:02:d0:ee:13  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1 
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

also

```
iwconfig   

lo        no wireless extensions. 

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off 
          Power Management:on 

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

and of course

```
sudo lshw -C network

  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface 
       product: 88E8055 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller 
       vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 
       physical id: 0 
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0 
       logical name: eth0 
       version: 12 
       serial: 00:17:42:14:e9:e1 
       size: 1Gbit/s 
       capacity: 1Gbit/s 
       width: 64 bits 
       clock: 33MHz 
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical     tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation 
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30  duplex=full firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s 
       resources: irq:44 memory:f0000000-f0003fff ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c0a00000-c0a1ffff 
  *-network DISABLED 
       description: Wireless interface 
       product: PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection 
       vendor: Intel Corporation 
       physical id: 0 
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0 
       logical name: wlan0 
       version: 02 
       serial: 00:13:02:d0:ee:13 
       width: 32 bits 
       clock: 33MHz 
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless 
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwl3945 driverversion=3.2.0-31-generic   firmware=15.32.2.9 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg 
       resources: irq:45 memory:c0100000-c0100fff
```

last but not least

```
lsmod


Module                  Size  Used by 
nls_iso8859_1          12617  0 
nls_cp437              12751  0 
vfat                   17308  0 
fat                    55605  1 vfat 
usb_storage            39646  0 
uas                    17828  0 
dm_crypt               22528  0 
rfcomm                 38139  0 
parport_pc             32114  0 
bnep                   17830  2 
ppdev                  12849  0 
bluetooth             158438  10 rfcomm,bnep 
binfmt_misc            17292  1 
snd_hda_codec_idt      60251  1 
pcmcia                 39791  0 
joydev                 17393  0 
snd_hda_intel          32765  3 
snd_hda_codec         109562  2 snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel 
snd_hwdep              13276  1 snd_hda_codec 
snd_pcm                80845  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec 
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
yenta_socket           27428  0 
snd_rawmidi            25424  1 snd_seq_midi 
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi 
snd_seq                51567  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event 
pcmcia_rsrc            18367  1 yenta_socket 
wacom_w8001            12906  0 
irda                  185517  0 
arc4                   12473  2 
iwl3945                73111  0 
iwl_legacy             71134  1 iwl3945 
mac80211              436455  2 iwl3945,iwl_legacy 
cfg80211              178679  3 iwl3945,iwl_legacy,mac80211 
snd_timer              28931  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq 
snd_seq_device         14172  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq 
dm_multipath           22710  0 
pcmcia_core            21511  3 pcmcia,yenta_socket,pcmcia_rsrc 
psmouse                96619  0 
apanel                 12718  0 
serport                12808  1 
serio_raw              13027  0 
crc_ccitt              12595  1 irda 
mac_hid                13077  0 
snd                    62064  15           snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_t    imer,snd_seq_device 
input_polldev          13648  1 apanel 
soundcore              14635  1 snd 
snd_page_alloc         14115  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm 
lp                     17455  0 
fujitsu_laptop         18504  0 
parport                40930  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp 
dm_raid45              76451  0 
xor                    25987  1 dm_raid45 
dm_mirror              21822  0 
dm_region_hash         16065  1 dm_mirror 
dm_log                 18193  3 dm_raid45,dm_mirror,dm_region_hash 
sdhci_pci              18324  0 
sdhci                  28241  1 sdhci_pci 
sky2                   49545  0 
i915                  414939  3 
drm_kms_helper         45466  1 i915 
drm                   197692  4 i915,drm_kms_helper 
i2c_algo_bit           13199  1 i915 
video                  19068  1 i915
```

Comment: Have you tried configuring your network connection's though Ubuntu's Network Manager? (click on the wireless symbo or the two arrows at the top of the screen, and click on Edit Connections.)

Comment: I dont even get a wireless option at the top of the screen anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to start network-manager with

```
service network-manager start
```

Alternatively, you may find that you need to edit /etc/network/interfaces and add a line similar to the following:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but the lines in my reply were incorrectly formatted to be all on the same line.  I have auto wlan0 / iface wlan0 inet dhcp / dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1 and it seems to be working fine.